# register_activation_hook in mu-plugin not triggering

Tags: plugins, mu-plugins

I have a class setup to run some database scripts on my mu-plugin.

```
function activate_mjmc_core() {
 require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-mjmc-core-activator.php';
 Mjmc_Core_Activator::activate();
 Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_database_version();
 Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_companies_table();
 Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_locations_table();
 Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_companies_insert();
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_mjmc_core' );
```

Now these work just fine when i use this as a normal plugin where i have to activate it.

But when i use this in my mu-plugins, all the other plugin functions work, it just doenst run the database functions listed above on activate.  Is there something else i need to do on these database functions? or run this on another wordpress hook?

thanks

Comment: How are you creating your tables? WP provides `dbDelta` which can create tables if they don't exist, and even update their schemas if you decide to change a column or add a new one

Comment: those are in the called functions and are working fine, just not being called since there is no mu-plugin activation hook. Jacob down below pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MU plugins don't 'activate', or 'deactivate'. They're just present or not present. So you'll need a different approach. One option would be to just perform your activation functions on `init`, and store a record in the database to say whether or not it's already been done:

```
function activate_mjmc_core() {
    if ( '1' === get_option( 'mjmc_activated' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-mjmc-core-activator.php';

    Mjmc_Core_Activator::activate();
    Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_database_version();
    Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_companies_table();
    Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_locations_table();
    Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_companies_insert();

    update_option( 'mjmc_activated', '1' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'activate_mjmc_core' );
```

Comment: also worth mentioning https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/#caveats

Comment: Right after i posted this, i finally found another option which i tried..(tweaking to get_option) https://wpengineer.com/2221/wordpress-multisite-plugins-and-activation/   but after seeing your answer, yours seems cleaner.. Thank you!!!

Comment: They're basically the same solution, that link use describes it in a full OOP context, and also accounts for Multisite. If your plugin is multisite compatible and has a separate database table for each site then you'll want to use `get_blog_option()`, like their example.

Answer (score -1):

You need to switch to siite for run this activation hook.

```
function activate_mjmc_core() {
$current_site_id = get_current_blog_id();
switch_to_blog($current_site_id);
require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-mjmc-core- 
activator.php';
Mjmc_Core_Activator::activate();
Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_database_version();
Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_companies_table();
Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_locations_table();
Mjmc_Core_Activator::mjmc_companies_insert();
restore_current_blog();
}
```

Hope this work. :D

register_activation_hook( **FILE**, 'activate_mjmc_core' );